# How to find current slide in Powerpoint Slideshow Window

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I create a Powerpoint add-in and I need to find which slide is active in Slideshow Window. I have this code:

```
if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.SlideShowWindows.Count > 0)
{
for (int s = 0; s < Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count; s++)
{
//abc
}
}
```

So I check if slideshow window is running and then go through all slides in presentation. But this is not very good solution. I want to get current slide immediately.

Comment: Try reading the documentation. Maybe the answer will be in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the VBA to do what you want.  It returns the index of the active slide in the first slideshow window:

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code .this is working for me..It may useful for new developers.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objPres;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowView oSlideShowView;
                objPres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
                objPres.SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
PowerPoint.Slide curSlide_1 = ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
                objPres.SlideShowSettings.Run();
                oSlideShowView = objPres.SlideShowWindow.View;                
                oSlideShowView.GotoSlide(curSlide_1.SlideIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

With C# in interop interface, you can use next call

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
```

Comment: Slide is returned as a dynamic. How do I get the slide number specifically? thanks!

Comment: Ah, the property is SlideIndex, same as the VBA